# Getting values and text from a jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get values and text from elements in a jQuery accordion. Their are two lists separate lists on the home page wrapped in  accordion. You can see the html/javascript below.

```
<!--Homepage Accordion-->
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" id="homepageAccordian" >
<!-- Crew List -->
                <div data-role="collapsible" id="collapsibleCrewList">
                    <h3>Current Crew</h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" id="crewList">
                            <li>Crew #1</li>
                            <li>Crew #2</li>
                            <li>Crew #3</li>
                            <li>Crew #4</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <script>
                    $(document).on('pageshow', '#TCHomepage', function(){
                        //alert('page show event fired');
                        checkSessionStorage();
                    }); 
                </script>
                <script>
                    $(document).on('click', '#crewList li a', function () {
                        clickOnCrewOnHomepage();
                    });
                </script>
<!-- Open Calls -->
                <div data-role="collapsible"id="collapsibleOpenCallsList">
                    <h3>Open Calls</h3>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" id="openCallsList">
                            <li>Call #1</li>
                            <li>Call #2</li>
                            <li>Call #3</li>
                            <li>Call #4</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <script>
                    $(document).on('click', '#openCallsList li a', function () {
                        clickOnTroubleCallOnHomepage();
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
```

My issue is that when you click on one of the links in the accordion I cannot get the value of the link or the text of the link clicked respectively. In my javascript file I am using these functions to try and grab the values or text.

`$(this).closest('li').attr('value');` and  `$(this).text();`

My event handler for both accordions is `$(document).on('click', '#crewList li a', function () { });` with the ids being different.

The problem is that these functions are not returning anything when the link is clicked.

Comment: I don't see any `<a>`s in the markup to trigger `$(document).on('click', '#crewList li a', function() { });`

Comment: @JasonP The event is triggered the issue was that I needed to have my `$(this).closest('li').attr('value');` and `$(this).text();` on the my main page and not in the javascript file. Moving the two functions to the page and then passing the variable to the function solved my issue.